# How can i create a shortCut item from inside a program?

Tags: java, installation, shortcut

we have created an installer to finish it off,

i want to make a shortcut for the normal software and place it on desktop,

but i wish to do this from my installer, can someone help me,

i wish to learn from this, so don't come spam answers like don't make your own installer, etc...

kind regards jonathan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/jimmc/jshortcut

shortcut library

"JShortcut is a JNI library to allow Java programs to create shortcuts
and menu items on Windows"

Answer (score 1):

Here is an explanation of the LNK-File-Format

http://www.stdlib.com/art6-Shortcut-File-Format-lnk.html

Answer (score 0):

[Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) can arrange shortcuts (or menu items) for any platform that supports them.  These can be specified in the [JNLP](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) file, or installed programmatically using the [IntegrationService](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/javax/jnlp/IntegrationService.html).